# Finding the maximum of $a_1$ given $2S_n=a^2_{n+1}-a_{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let sequence $\{a_n\}$ be$$2S_n=a^2_{n+1}-a_{n+1},\ \forall n\in N^+$$
>   where $S_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$, and $a_2=a_9$, then the maximum of the $a_1$ is:
>
> A. $3\qquad\qquad$ B. $6\qquad\qquad$ C. $9\qquad\qquad$ D. $12$

I try some
$$2S_{n}=a^2_{n+1}-a_{n+1}$$
$$2S_{n-1}=a^2_{n}-a_{n}$$
so
$$2a_{n}=2S_{n}-2S_{n-1}=(a^2_{n+1}-a_{n+1})-(a^2_{n}-a_{n})$$
so we have
$$(a_{n}+a_{n+1})(a_{n+1}-a_{n}-1)=0$$
so $a_{n+1}=-a_{n}$or  $ a_{n+1}-a_{n}=1$
so $a_{2}=-a_{3}=a_{4}=\cdots=-a_{9}$
or
$$a_{2}=a_{1}+d,a_{9}=a_{1}+8d$$
this two case I can't get right answer,so How to solve it? Thanks

Maybe I think it's alternate values.such this two condtion
$$a_{n+1}=-a_{n},a_{n+1}-a_{n}=1$$
for example $a_{2}=-a_{1},a_{3}-a_{2}=1,a_{4}-a_{3}=1,\cdots $or
$$a_{2}-a_{1}=1,a_{3}=-a_{2},\cdots$$ and so on

Comment: Not sure if this helps at all, but $2S_{n}=2S_{n-1}+2a_{n}=2\left(a_{n}^{2}-a_{n}\right)+2a_{n}=2a_{n}^{2}\implies S_{n}=a_{n}^{2}$.

Comment: @Jake,maybe can help

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if $S_{n}=a_{n}^{2}$, then $a_{1}=S_{1}=a_{1}^{2}$, so $a_{1}^{2}-a_{1}=0\implies a_{1}=0$ or $a_{1}=1$, so the maximum value of $a_{1}$ is $1$?

Comment: Does the question state a value of $s_{1}$ or what type of series this is, e.g. arithmetic, geometric, etc.?

Comment: @Jake, $2s_{n}=2s_{n-1}+2a_{n}$,this $n\ge 2$